# Upsert records after parsing JSON response

Tags: apex, rest-api, controller, callout, dml

I have a requirement to upsert Policy records using JSON response obtained from external system.

below is my apex code:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setMethod('GET');
  req.setTimeout(120000);
  req.setEndpoint('<endpoint>'); 
  req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + '<bearer token>');
  Http http = new Http();
  HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
  String response = res.getBody();
JsonParser jsondes = (JsonParser) JSON.deserialize(response, JsonParser.class);
```

I have a JSON Parser class and it is as follows:

```
public class JSONParser{
    public Integer code;
    public cls_value value;
    public class cls_value {
        public cls_data[] data;
        public String message;
        public Integer code;    
    }
    public class cls_data {
        public String agencyName;
        public String agentID;  
        public string id;   
    }
}
```

Now, from the above code peice, **ID** is unique and **if the id matches with existing Policy__c's Unique_ID__c field value, the record should be updated. Else, the record should be inserted**.

Can anyone please let me know on how to do so.

***********************Update*********************__**

Below is the code block which I am using to update the existing policy records when the id is matched with unique id

```
list<policy__c> pollist = new list<policy__c>();
for (String eachIdFromMap : clsDataMap.keySet()){
    if(!accountMap.isEmpty() && accountMap.containsKey(eachIdFromMap)){
        for(policy__c pol : pollist){
       pol.unique_id__c = clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap).id;
            update pol;
        } 
    } else {
        system.debug('False');
    }
}
```

I am not seeing any error but the records arent getting updated.

Thanks!

Comment: Iterate over `cls_data` and create a map `Map<Id, cls_data> (MapA)`, then you can do a SOQL with the map KeySet and fetch all the policies and fetch it like a map `Map<Id, Policy__c> (MapB)`., Then iterate over Map A, and check if the MapA's key exists on MapB, if yes then fire an update orelse fire an insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over cls_data and create a map Map<Id, cls_data> (MapA), then you can do a SOQL with the map KeySet and fetch all the policies and fetch it like a map Map<Id, Policy__c> (MapB)., Then iterate over Map A, and check if the MapA's key exists on MapB, if yes then fire an update orelse fire an insert.

For example something like this would work:

```
String str = '{"value":{"message":"Success","data":[{"id":"TestId","agentID":"TestAgenctId","agencyName":"TestAgencyName"},{"id":"TestId","agentID":"TestAgenctId","agencyName":"TestAgencyName"}],"code":200},"code":200}';

JSONParser1 objJsonParser = (JSONParser1) JSON.deserializeStrict(str, JSONParser1.class);

JSONParser1.cls_value clsValue = objJsonParser.value;
Map<String, JSONParser1.cls_data> clsDataMap = new Map<String, JSONParser1.cls_data>();

// Iterate from Object
for(JSONParser1.cls_data objClsData: clsValue.data){
    clsDataMap.put(objClsData.id, objClsData);
}

// Query on Policy
Map<ID, Policy__c> accountMap = new Map<ID, Policy__c>([SELECT Id, Name FROM Policy__c WHERE Id IN :clsDataMap.keySet()]);

// Iterate again and update or insert
for (String eachIdFromMap : clsDataMap.keySet()){
    if(!accountMap.isEmpty() && accountMap.containsKey(eachIdFromMap)){
        // Update
    } else {
        // Insert
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the update @Narendra. To update policy__c object records, could you please let me know how to call field values from eachIdFromMap? Is it eachIdFromMap.agentid and eachIdFromMap.id? 

Please suggest

Comment: As its a key from map, you need to fire `clsDataMap.get(eachIdFromMap)` which will give you `SONParser1.cls_data`, from there you can fetch the `agentId` and 'id'

Comment: @NarendraSingh, I am getting this following error "Incompatible types since an instance of List<Policy__c> is never an instance of Map<Id,Policy__c>;" Could you please suggest any update here?

Comment: Can you show some code what have you tried ?

Comment: I havent made any changes to the given changes @Narendra except for variable change. I could see that the error is from Map<Id, Policy__c> accountMap line

Comment: My bad, updated that line. It was a compilation error.

Comment: @SFDCUser Can you please accept the answer if it works?

Comment: when I am trying to update the policy record, I am not seeing any error but the records arent getting updated. Could you please suggest any changes to the updated code in the question above. Thanks!

Comment: Error message is self explanatory. And why are you firing a DML in loop? We cannot write the whole code for you, we can guide you to right direction or provide an algorithm. Please do more research on your own.